# How to combine two pre-trained Word2Vec models?

Tags: java, nlp, emoji, word2vec, deeplearning4j

I successfully followed deeplearning4j.org tutorial on Word2Vec, so I am able to load already trained model or train a new one based on some raw text (more specifically, I am using `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300` and `Emoji2Vec` pre-trained model).

However, I would like to combine these two above models for the following reason: Having a sentence (for example, a comment from Instagram or Twitter, which consists of emoji), I want to identify the emoji in the sentence and then map it to the word it is related to. In order to do that, I was planning to iterate over all the words in the sentence and calculate the closeness (how near the emoji and the word are located in the vector space).

I [found the code](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/nlp/word2vec/Word2VecUptrainingExample.java) how to uptrain the already existing model. However, it is mentioned that new words are not added in this case and only weights for the existing words will be updated based on a new text corpus.

I would appreciate any help or ideas on the problem I have. Thanks in advance!

Comment: feel free to join the DL4J dev support community on gitter: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Comment: Thanks! I joined the community on Gitter, however, nobody could answer my question yet. Maybe I need to restructure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining two models trained from different corpuses is not a simple, supported operation in the word2vec libraries with which I'm most familiar.

In particular, even if the same word appears in both corpuses, and even in similar contexts, the randomization that's used by this algorithm during initialization and training, and extra randomization injected by multithreaded training, mean that word may appear in wildly different places. It's only the *relative* distances/orientation with respect to other words that should be roughly similar – not the specific coordinates/rotations.

So to merge two models requires translating one's coordinates to the other. That in itself will typically involve learning-a-projection from one space to the other, then moving unique words from a source space to the surviving space. I don't know if DL4J has a built-in routine for this; the Python `gensim` library has a `TranslationMatrix` example class in recent versions which can do this, as motivated by the use of word-vectors for language-to-language translations.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how large are the vectors already. If they are still compat enough, one can easily concat the vectors from two spaces for each word and perform similarity or operations based on the concatenated vectors, i.e. if model 1 has a word embedding size of 300 and model 2 has an embedding size of 200, then the combine model would simply be a concatenation per word and each word would have an embedding of size 300+200.